Korach - Why Moshe needed to ask Hashem not to accept their incense?
In Parshat Korach 16:15 it says:

וַיִּ֤חַר לְמֹשֶׁה֙ מְאֹ֔ד וַיֹּ֙אמֶר֙ אֶל־יְהֹוָ֔ה אַל־תֵּ֖פֶן
אֶל־מִנְחָתָ֑ם לֹ֠א חֲמ֨וֹר אֶחָ֤ד מֵהֶם֙ נָשָׂ֔אתִי וְלֹ֥א הֲרֵעֹ֖תִי
אֶת־אַחַ֥ד מֵהֶֽם׃
Moses was much aggrieved and he said to יהוה, “Pay no regard to their
oblation. I have not taken the ass of any one of them, nor have I
wronged any one of them.”

According to most commentators, at least that I’ve seen, they see this as directed specifically to them and not on the whole group (as Chizkuni spells out very clearly). According to Sforno it seems that Moshe is basically putting a “block” that even if Hashem wanted to accept their offering, since Moshe does not forgive them and it’s a sin between man and man, then even Hashem can’t forgive them.
I have two questions:

Whats the hava Mina to begin with that Moshe thought that Hashem would accept their incense that he had to specifically ask Hashem not to accept it? Ibn Ezra seems to hint at some kind of merit that they have that would have allowed their incense to be accepted. What merit is this and again why would that triumph their actions now (even if you answer according to Ramban that seems to say that they didn’t even participate in the burning of the incense and rather it refers to praying, the question still stands)

Chizkuni understands that because Datan and Aviram were challenging all of priesthood and the rest of the group including Korach were only challenging Aaron specifically being appointed, that’s why Moshe only prayed for their incense/prayers to not get answered. From his words it also seems to hint that there was a chance that the rest of the groups incense would get accepted (but because their intentions weren’t as severe it was ok)… so even if you answer to question one about the tremendous merit Datan and Aviram had that Moshe was “worried”, according to Chizkuni what was the merit the remaining group had that Hashem would have accepted their incense?



Hah! I had the same question today

Not sure how this community views someone answering their your own question but I thought it’s chaval to delete in the case that someone has a similar question in the future and over Shabbat I found an answer that at least satisfied me so I wanted to share:
The Ohr HaChaim Hakadosh answers these questions:

ויאמר אל ה׳ אל תפן, He said to G'd: "do not turn to their
gift-offering." Moses now understood the depth of Datan and Aviram's
hatred, that they were thoroughly wicked and actually hated anything
or anybody who was good. He was aware that there are no people who do
not have certain merits due to good deeds they have performed. He
realised that G'd does not withhold the reward for such merits from
anyone, and that if the people in question cannot be rewarded in the
hereafter because they had forfeited their hereafter, G'd would
compensate them in this life. This is based on Deut. 32,4 that "the
Lord is one of faithfulness without iniquity." Sanhedrin 106 provides
us with an example of the wicked Bileam, who had after all pronounced
all the blessings on the Jewish people, collecting his fee for having
the Moabites seduce the Israelites, prior to his being slain. Moses
did not want G'd to accept even the good deeds Korach and associates
had performed for whom they had not yet received a reward. This is
what he had in mind when he referred to מנחתם.
Be aware that the righteous possess the power to annul merits which
the wicked have accumulated when they observe that the potential
recipients have become thoroughly wicked. This is the mystical
dimension of Samuel II 23,3 צדיק מושל יראת אלוקים, "The righteous
rules in matters of G'd-fearingness." This means that G'd has given
the righteous leeway to cancel merits that the wicked have acquired.
The idea is that although G'd Himself does not do this, He has allowed
the righteous to be His surrogates in this respect. This is not so
surprising as the same principle which has been adopted by a court in
our world which has the right to deprive an accused of property he
owns under the heading of הפקר בית דין הפקר, that when a Jewish court
declares certain property as ownerless such a declaration is binding
(compare Gittin 36). When Moses said the words את אחד מהם, this
included that he was not even involved when one Jew hurt another Jew
in some way. He had never given a verdict in which the guilty had been
exonerated, nor had he issued a verdict in which the innocent had been
declared guilty. If, as a result of his decision, one party had to pay
money to a second party this was not Moses' doing but the guilty party
had caused that loss to the other. Seeing that Moses possessed
sufficient prophetic insight not to make awards to people who did not
deserve them from people who were innocent of wrongdoing, he could say
of himself that he had not wronged anybody during his career as leader
of the nation. Inasmuch as Datan and Aviram's hatred of him could only
be the result of bad character, Moses felt entitled to ask G'd to
deprive these men of any merits they might have accumulated in their
lives and for which they had not yet been recompensed. I believe that
the wicked people concerning whom Moses offered this prayer, i.e.
Datan and Aviram, were not considered by him as part of the
congregation of Korach concerning whom we applied the verse from
Samuel I that their share in the resurrection had already been assured
(compare Sanhedrin 108). The souls of these men (Datan and Aviram)
must have had their roots in the קליפה, the spiritually negative
domain of Satan.

